# Resolving/Rejecting Promises, what are the differences?

Tags: javascript, promise

### Story

All my life I have always used the following code pattern in my promises:

```
const => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //do some work
    if(err !== undefined){
        reject(err);
        return;
    }

    if(someCondition){
        resolve(1);
        return;
    }

    resolve(2);
});
```

However, recently one of my pupils presented me with an interesting code:

```
const => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //do some work
    if(err !== undefined) return reject(err);

    if(someCondition) return resolve(1);

    resolve(2);
});
```

**My first reaction was:** "You should do it my way because... (*silence followed*)"

### Problem

I tried finding a logical explanation for the difference and I couldn't find one.

I tried checking the MDN documentation for Promises to see if resolve or reject could return something other than `undefined` but I didn't find it either.

### Question:

So now I am left with one question:
 -  What are the differences (if any) between my approach and my pupil's approach, code functionality wise? (AKA, will they **always** return the same output and have the same behaviour under the same conditions?)

Comment: `will they always return the same output and have the same behaviour under the same conditions?` yes - the returned value of the promise executor is ignored, besides that, the returned value in both cases is always `undefined` anyway

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am young in spirit my friend! That's what counts ! :D

Comment: doing `return reject()` or `return resolve()` is ambiguous, returning `reject` or `resolve` does not do anything special, the moment you use `reject` or `resolve` the promise is placed in a rejected for `reject`  or fulfilled for `resolve` state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the differences (if any) between my approach and my pupil's approach, code functionality wise?

In *this specific situation*, there aren't any, for three reasons:

1. The `resolve` and `reject` functions passed to the Promise executor (the function you pass `new Promise`) [are defined as](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions) returning `undefined`. So `return resolve(...)` is effectively `resolve(...); return undefined;`
2. The Promise constructor [doesn't use the return value of the executor](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-executor), so even if #1 weren't true, it still wouldn't matter.
3. In a function, the difference between `return;` and `return undefined;` is present at a specification level, but not observable in code. That is, in code, they do exactly the same thing, even though the spec differentiates them slightly.

---

It's probably worth noting that while it doesn't make a *functionality* difference, it makes a semantic difference. `return resolve(...)` says "call `resolve` and return its return value" — suggesting that that return value has meaning and matters to the code. It doesn't, so `return resolve(...)` is misleading to people maintaining the code later. As a matter of style, I don't recommend it. (Mind you, if it becomes common enough, it becomes an idiom, and the confusion to resolved by knowing the idiom, but...) If saving the line is important to you, just do `resolve(...); return;` (or better yet, don't worry about the extra line, or make your logic not require the `return` at all). But your question was about differences in functionality, so...

---

**That said**, it's dangerous to generalize this to other situations where the function you're calling may not return `undefined`, or where the return value of your function is used.

Comment: What about in other situations ? Will `return resolve(X)` always equal the behaviour of `resolve(X); return;` ?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: Oddly, I was just adding a warning to underscore what I meant by "in this specific situation." The answer to that is "Yes, for the resolution functions passed to the promise executor" and "No, not in the general case."

Comment: Ahh, so in any given case `return reject(X)` will always equal the behaviour of  `reject(X); return`. Same thing for resolve. This is exactly what I needed to know. Thanks !

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: For the promise resolution functions, yes; see #1 above.

Answer (score 1):

They will always behave in exactly the same way, yes, as the `resolve` and `reject` functions passed to the executor both return `undefined` and `return undefined` is equivalent to `return` (and the promise constructor doesn’t use the value you return anyway).

Typically, you won’t want to use the `Promise` constructor much at all, though. This one looks like something that could make use of `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject`, for example:

```
// do some work
if (err !== undefined) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
}

if (someCondition) {
    return Promise.resolve(1);
}

return Promise.resolve(2);
```

Comment: My code is an hypothetical example. I am well aware of how it could be optimised, but for the purposes of this question I figured the simplifying the answer was important :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the 2 code examples, they will both act exactly the same. The only difference is if you had to perform additional logic before resolving / rejecting, e.g. clearing variables, the first approach would be more readable. Other than that it is just readability. You can remove the {} around conditionals if you only need to execute 1 line within the condition

Answer (score 0):

[From the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise),

> We call resolve(...) when what we were doing asynchronously was
>   successful, and reject(...) when it failed.

So yes, the code examples will always return the same thing, though as another person has mentioned it's not a very good code snippet.

Comment: We do need the return. Consider my first code piece without the return statements and where `error !== undefined`. If you test it in chrome you will see resolve being called as well! PS: I am **NOT** the guy who down-voted your answer!

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix you're right, thanks for correcting me.